# Including correct C++ redist with an application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, vcredist

I build my application in `Microsoft Visual Studio 2010`, and want to bundle it with `vcredist`, but I have to do it manually. Is there a way to automatically get `vcredist` corresponding to the one I used to build my application? I need only x64 support.

For instance `Microsoft Visual Studio 2012` is bundled with `vcredist` already (it is found under `Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\redist\1033`). `Microsoft Visual Studio 2010` has similar folder, but there are no executables or packages, only the `*.dll` files which is not a good option to distribute I think.

Comment: Not sure if tagging this question with `visual-studio-2012` and `c++` is correct, because these are not exactly related. Should I remove these tags?

Comment: The current redist for the current patch level of your visual studio install should be in the VC/redist folder. And if memory serves it should include an MSI package for easy integration into your installer.

Comment: @WhozCraig I can not find such MSI package, only the *.dll files. Could you point out where could it probably be? Or is there maybe some way I can force Studio to redownload this package and store it?

Comment: In my CMake files, I automagically find the redist by looking in the registry: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE]\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft\Windows\v7.1;InstallationFolder\Redist\

Comment: @Andre I don't have such path, though have a resembling path to Win SDK: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A`. But there is nothing about redist.

Answer (score 1):

From this [legal reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/ff727939.aspx) about what you can distribute I assume that the file you need is `vs100_piaredist` located in `Program Files\Common Files\Merge Modules`.

Answer (score 0):

VS2010 also have the similar folder "/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/redist"

Comment: yes, it does, but that is not an installer unlike in VS2012 case